# Why should we use yml over properties

Tags: spring, properties, yaml

If we put `spring.datasource.url = url` it takes only one line.

However, If we put same thing in `.yml` it takes 4  lines.

```
spring : 
  datasource:
    url : url
```

Yet developers and frameworks(like `Spring`) prefer `.yml` over `.properties`.

Why should we use `.yml` over `.properties` file?

Comment: Questions about "What are pros and cons" are generally avoided on Stack Overflow, as they are badly fit for Q/A format. Listing all features in the one answer would be "too broad", but if some answer would list only some of features, how would you compare it (from the view of votes or acceptance) with other answers?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've updated question.

Answer (score 5):

Some Googling would have definitely helped you.

Ex : From http://javajee.com/a-quick-comparison-of-yaml-with-properties-file ,

> YAML supports Maps, lists and scalar types. YAML is hierarchical and may use consistent spaces to denote hierarchy.

and,

> Properties file is mainly used with Java, supports only String types and is non-hierarchical; we can have maps by denoting hierarchies as dots

Another long and descriptive guide is http://hsoienterprises.com/2014/03/10/property-list-vs-json-vs-yaml/ , which I'll leave for you to read.